# How to change the title color when using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am creating my own action bar with menu items and therefore using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

I want to have the action bar purple and the title color white, but at the moment it is black.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

my action bar xml is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:id="@+id/app_bar"
>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in this [Google+ pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/AV2ooBWY1iy), you can use a `ThemeOverlay` to customize only certain things. This is useful for when you need to make text light on a dark background, which can be achieved by adding `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` to your `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:id="@+id/app_bar"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>
```

This technique was further discussed in the [Theming with AppCompat blog+video](https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35).